# How to run asynchronous functions inside of the discord python api

Tags: python, discord

I'm making a discord bot which you can interact with by adding reactions, and i want to add quite a bit of options options. Awaiting the add_reaction call takes too long for my use case, and i want to do it asynchronously. How would i go about this?

Code:

```
import discord

token = "#####"

client = discord.Client()

voting_options = ["\U0001F1E6", "\U0001F1E7", "\U0001F1E8", "\U0001F1E9", "\U0001F1EA"]

@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.content == ".poll":
        message = await client.send_message(ctx.channel, "Vote now!")
        for option in voting_options:
            await client.add_reaction(message, option)

client.run(token)
```

Result:
https://gyazo.com/ae31b98bed42ef2358f2227026df4263

How would i go about making this threaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 asyncio.create_task(client.add_reaction(message, option))
```

to create a task. However, that is not threaded, but asynchronously (thats how asyncio works), but I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I had to update to python 3.7 but it worked nicely once i did!